# Force.drag().on returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Im using the sticky force layout : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558

Im trying to implement the sticky drag in my layout. So I have something like this :

```
    force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-120)
        .linkDistance(30)
        .size([width, height])
        .on("tick", tick);;

        var nodeDrag = force.drag()
        .on("dragstart", dragstart);

//then for drag i call nodeDrag on the node after I append circle :

.call(nodeDrag)



function dragstart(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}
```

This returns the error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined`

Which points at the line : `var nodeDrag = force.drag()`

If I use `d3.behavior.drag()`, it loads the visualization but I can't drag, as I'm guessing it's not using my `force` layout.

Any ideas ?

Comment: try changing force to force.drag()? just a guess

Comment: Try to make a fiddle with your sample data, so that we can figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself. Basically I had to work out the movement myself, that's why none of the nodes were working. So I implemented it like so :

```
var nodeDrag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart) //-when you first click
    .on("drag", dragmove) //-when you're dragging
    .on("dragend", dragend); //-when the drag has ended

function dragstart(d, i) //-ability to move nodes to one place and keep them there
{
    force.stop(); //-stop the force layout as soon as you move nodes
}

function dragmove(d, i) //-updates the co-ordinates 
{
    //d.px += d3.event.dx;
    //d.py += d3.event.dy;
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy; 


    d3.select(this).attr("transform", function(d,i)
    {
        return "translate(" + [ d.x,d.y ] + ")";
    });
    tick(); //-updates positions

}

function dragend(d, i) //-when you stop dragging the node
{
    d.fixed = true; //-D3 giving the node a fixed attribute
    tick(); //-update positions
}
```

The main reason why the nodes weren't moving is because I wasn't telling them to move. Also, calling tick updated the positions of all the other nodes. Hope that helps someone that runs across the same problem :)